# Filling columns of modified flags for old revisions in Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm adding modified flags to an already existing audit table. The flags for new revisions added to the table are filled correctly but I want the flags for already existing revisions to be filled.

I could procedurally check revisions for changes and update the columns, but it would take a lot of time to write an specific procedure for each table.

For example, this is the data of a user from my `user_aud` table before adding the columns:

```
id  |rev  |revtype|username     |password
100 |51544|1      |pdacostaporto|420bed36a05fa4668b1baeff18ffce96
100 |46343|0      |pdacostaporto|286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4
```

When I set `withModifiedFlag` to `true` in my `User` entity as this:

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class User {
   // Attributes, getters and setters...
}
```

then, Hibernate adds the columns for the flags, but with `null` values on existing rows while working as expected for new revisions:

```
id  |rev  |revtype|username     |password                         |username_mod |password_mod
100 |60745|1      |pdacostaporto|4305664d643844973ccb52cbb7c369f8 |false        |true
100 |51544|1      |pdacostaporto|420bed36a05fa4668b1baeff18ffce96 |null         |null
100 |46343|0      |pdacostaporto|286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4 |null         |null
```

I would like to fill the `null` columns of already existing rows with the correct values, as this:

```
id  |rev  |revtype|username     |password                         |username_mod |password_mod
100 |60745|1      |pdacostaporto|4305664d643844973ccb52cbb7c369f8 |false        |true
100 |51544|1      |pdacostaporto|420bed36a05fa4668b1baeff18ffce96 |false        |true
100 |46343|0      |pdacostaporto|286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4 |false        |false
```

Comment: Which database platform are you using?

Comment: @Naros I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no automated way that Envers will update existing audit history rows for that feature if you enable it after a table has existing data; that is something which you have to do manually.

If you decide to do this manually, here's the logic:

1. Rows with `REVTYPE=0` will always have the `_MOD` columns equal to `true` or `1`.  I noticed you had them set to `false` in your original question and that's incorrect and may create query problems.
2. Rows with `REVTYPE!=0` will only be set to `true` or `1` if the value for the data column is different from the value in the same column in the prior revision.

Ideally, you should be able to make use of the database's metadata and write a single script that would take a table name and perform all the necessary operations regardless of the table.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should correct the REVTYPE=0 case in the question?

Comment: It won't affect day-to-day operations.  The only impact it would have is if you use any of the has changed apis on queries that those with `REVTYPE=0` might return the row wasn't changed when obviously it did.